# R: Convert Extent Object to Shapefile

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, extents

I want to convert R 'library:raster' '*extent*' object to a shapefile. I have the CRS available too.

```
  e=  c(4304916, 4305325, 365216, 365439)#xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax
  proj4string(e) = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=18 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs")
```

In older version of raster data there was a specific function ""
'extentTopolygon' which is depreciated now. My current approach is to create a raster object change its projection and assign the current extent and convert it to shapefile, which is not very efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
library(terra)
e <- ext( c(4304916, 4305325, 365216, 365439) )
p <- as.polygons(e)
crs(p) <- "+proj=utm +zone=18 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m"
writeVector(p, 'file.shp')
```

Or with the raster package

```
library(raster)
e <- extent( c(4304916, 4305325, 365216, 365439) )
p <- as(e, 'SpatialPolygons')
crs(p) <- "+proj=utm +zone=18 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"
shapefile(p, 'file.shp')
```

Comment: Just a comment--the coordinates are given are swapped. The four million values are the 'y' or northing values while the three hundred thousand values are the 'x' or easting values.

Comment: @mkennedy. How so? I do not think so. See `plot(p, axes=TRUE)`

Comment: Okay, I don't see that in the question or answer (in the current versions), but UTM is always easting,northing so...? You know the software, not me.

Comment: right, and easting is x, and northing is y, hence the order